# Android Kotlin - How do i set a default value for DialogInterface.OnClickListener as function parameter?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, onclicklistener, function-parameter

This is my function declaration:

```
fun MyDialog(ctx: Context, msg: String, yestext: String = "", OnYes: DialogInterface.OnClickListener): AlertDialog
```

How do i set a default value for "OnYes: DialogInterface.OnClickListener"?

I have tried OnYes: DialogInterface.OnClickListener = null but it doesn't work.

Comment: You want to make an alert dialog?

Comment: Yes it is a utility function to create a dialog which should support both dialog with or without a yes button, hence the need of optional parameter for yes button text and the OnClickListener.

Comment: OnYes: DialogInterface.OnClickListener? = null , you forgot the question mark to make it nullable

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks mangkool!

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided by @mangkool

OnYes: DialogInterface.OnClickListener? = null

Answer (score 0):

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity)

            // Set the alert dialog title
            builder.setTitle("App background color")

            // Display a message on alert dialog
            builder.setMessage("Are you want to set the app background color to RED?")

            // Set a positive button and its click listener on alert dialog
            builder.setPositiveButton("YES"){dialog, which ->
                // Do something when user press the positive button
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Ok, we change the app background.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                // Change the app background color
                root_layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED)
            }


            // Display a negative button on alert dialog
            builder.setNegativeButton("No"){dialog,which ->
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You are not agree.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }


            // Display a neutral button on alert dialog
            builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel"){_,_ ->
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"You cancelled the dialog.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            // Finally, make the alert dialog using builder
            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()

            // Display the alert dialog on app interface
            dialog.show()
```

Comment: What do you mean? @AnimeshSahu

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question, or has it?

Comment: In comments of question he said that he wanted to make alert dialog, I gave him an example @AnimeshSahu